# Android: ListFragment, no data and data is loading situations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have got ListFragment in my application.

*And I got 2 possible situations:*

1. When data is loading (from internet or database)
2. When data count is zero

**So, what is the best way to show that to user?**

I have tryed to use `@android:id/empty` but it is showing in both of situations. I can not control its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:
1. Spinning progressbar while the data is loading
2. a short toast stating "No data" or something meaningful if the list is empty.

Comment: Heh, I know how to show it, if you talking about ui things. I do not know how to do it in ListFragment code...

Comment: Last time I did it like this:  1: start new asynctask with spinning progressbar.  2: start downloading your data(not from the asynctask).  3: dismiss spinning progressbar(from the datadownload method).  4: check if the list is empty(the data is usually stored temporarily in an array or something) and display a toast if it is.  I know i really should include a code sample here, but I can barely keep my eyes open as it is, so sorry.